# variable scope. Python

Tags: python

A question is about variable scope.
Why next next `function2` modifies list `l`

```
def function1():
    myvar = 1
    l = []
    def function2():                                                             
        l.append(3)
    function2()
    print l
```

But it gives error "local variable 'myvar' referenced before assignment", if I add next line `myvar = 4`,

```
 def function1():
    myvar = 1
    l = []
    def function2():
        myvar += 4                                                               
        l.append(3)
    function2()
    print l
```

How to modify `myvar` that is local to `function1` within `function2` without making `myvar` belong to the module scope (module global variable)?
References to documentation are appreciated!

Comment: You are never **assigning** to `l` in `function2`. Binding (assignment) determines scope. You are rebinding `myvar` so it is local, unless you tell python with a `nonlocal` or `global` keyword to treat it differently.